# How can I get my XSL to preserve blanks in an element attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I cannot get my XSL to preserve the whitespace of an attribute value. I have XML that looks like this:

```
<FUNCTION_CALL name="SUBSTR">
    <ARGUMENTS>
            <CONSTANT type="CHAR" value="        "/>
            <CONSTANT type="NUMERIC" value="1"/>
            <CONSTANT type="NUMERIC" value="8"/>
    </ARGUMENTS>
</FUNCTION_CALL>
```

And I need to render:

```
SUBSTR('          ', 1, 8)
```

however, I am getting

```
SUBSTR('', 1, 8)
```

The XSL I have is:

```
<xsl:template match="FUNCTION_CALL">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FUNCTION_CALL[@ALIAS]">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:apply-templates/> AS <xsl:value-of select="@ALIAS"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ARGUMENTS">
(
<xsl:for-each select="COLUMN | CONSTANT">
    <xsl:if test="position()&gt;1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:for-each> 
)   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CONSTANT[@type='CHAR']" xml:space="preserve">
    '<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>'
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried `xml:space="preserve"` (in the sample code), `<xsl:preserve-space elements="CONSTANT" />`, and `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>` but can not render the output with the spaces.  I am a relative beginner at XSL and XSLT and could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

You may be a victim of XML's [attribute value normalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#AVNormalize), a process that mangles whitespace in attribute values, and which conformant parsers are required to perform. You could inhibit this by escaping the spaces in the attribute, e.g. `value="&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;"`